# Rearranging an equation to find $s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a previous question I asked one of the answers involved re-arranging an equation to find s. In the answer, the original equation and the final one (with the variables re-arranged) were provided, but I was unable to follow the steps (no working was provided).

The equation is

$$L^2=r^2+s^2-2rs\cos\theta\tag1$$

I am trying to isolate $s$. I'm having trouble with this oen because after subtracting $r^2$ on both sides im left with $$L^2-r^2=s^2-2rs\cos\theta$$

From here on I dont know how to isolate s. Do I factorize it to get $L^2-r^2=s(s-2r\cos\theta)$? If I do this I dont know how to simplify any further than that, because when if I multiply by $(s-2r\cos\theta)$ on both sides im left with an equation that has $s$ on both sides, which isnt very helpful.

Im not sure if this helps, but this is how $(1)$ equation looked after re-arranging for s

$$s=r\cos\theta+ \sqrt{L^2-r^2\sin^2\theta}$$

Essentially what im asking for is some guidance on how tos re-arrange the equation step by step.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What is this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation $(1)$ is a second degree equation on $s$. It is equivalent to$$s^2-2sr\cos\theta+r^2-L^2=0,$$which can be solved applyig the quadratic formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, after applying the quadratic formula I get $r\cos\theta+\sqrt{r^2 \cos^2(\theta)-r^2-L^2}$. How does the $\cos^2\theta$ turn into a $\sin^2\theta$? And where does the $-r^2$ go?

Comment: Actually, what you get is$$r\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2+L^2}=r\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{L^2-r^2\sin^2\theta},$$since $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.